# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Where would one go to nominate someone (not me) for moderator? I found only a link to nominate myself.

Comment: @Stan The idea is that candidates should always nominate *themselves*, thus indicating that they would be willing to take on the task. (Being a mod isn’t for everyone, and yes, there’s some time and dedication required.) There’s also a Meta Q/A *somewhere*, which explains in more detail. But if you’d like to encourage a user to run, that’s absolutely ok. Sometimes a gentle nudge is a good thing...

Comment: Ah, found it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75382/how-can-you-nominate-someone-other-than-yourself-for-being-a-moderator and follow the link in Jeff’s post for more details, if you like.

Comment: I love this community, and I've been toying with the idea of nominating myself. But I can't find out what a moderator DOES. What is required? How often does the mod need to do something a user can't? What powers does a mod have? I think it boils down to this: what would be expected of me, and what would happen if I didn't live up to those expectations? There's gotta be an answer to this somewhere. (TBH, this is my first time in the Meta section.)

Comment: @BrettFromLA First this is a volunteer position, you don't have to do anything.  Being a mod does not give you much more power then you already have as a high rep user.  A couple of things to read for your questions [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) & [What can Moderators and Trusted Users see that others can't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90844/217279) in short the expectation is that  you will visit the site regularly and see if anything needs your help.  There is chat room just for mods where you can get help if needed.

Comment: @BrettFromLA continued: If you think you might like to try it, nominate yourself.  For the most part being a mod just means that you get notice when some one flags a post, and if you vote to close or open or delete, it will happen without waiting for more votes.

Comment: @Stan You can reach out to the person and suggest that they might be a good candidate.  Ping them in a chat room or under a post and let them know you think they would be a good fit.

Comment: @BrettFromLA and if you have more questions, ping either James or me in [chat]. I am a mod on two SE sites, James on one (afaik). Plus, remember that there’s a community of mods (first, the ones of the site, second, across the network) who can help you get started and support you if you need it.